# Any GoogleMap-like style for OpenStreetMap?

Tags: linux, debian, openstreetmap, mapnik

I have just built a tile server for OSM. I'm wondering if I could have a GoogleMap-like style shown in browser. If yes, how could I make it?

Comment: Interesting question. I've never seen an OSM style that attempts to mimic google maps. One suggestion for "how could I make it" is using TileMill: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/

Comment: To answer the first part of your question: This is possible of course. You just need such a rendering style sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various styles that contains less details than the official OSM style and some that really look like Google Maps:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles

Comment: Now that I've downloaded a style sheet, how could I use it? Just replace the old osm.xml with the new one?

Comment: Yes replacing or patching the server config to use your new style instead.

Answer (score 6):

I've found a style "[OSM bright](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright)". I think it's a good substitution for google style. They are similar.